# Cannot import tensorflow_text

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have problem with importing `tensorflow_text` I tried importing like below two methods but none of them worked

```
import tensorflow_text as text
import tensorflow_text as tf_text
```

My tensorflow version is `2.9.1` and python version is `Python 3.7.13`. I tried installing `tensorflow_text` using below two methods but none of them is working.

```
!pip install tensorflow-text
!pip install -U tensorflow-text==2.9.0
```

I am using colab, I also tried reinstalling tensorflow but it still generates below error.

```
NotFoundError: 
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distpackages/tensorflow_text/python/ops/_sentencepiece_tokenizer.so: 
undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**, Sometimes you need to reinstall and update `tensorflow` then install `tensorflow_text`. *(Because you need your `tensorflow.__version__` and `tensorflow_text.__version__` to have the same version)*

```
!pip install -U tensorflow
!pip install -U tensorflow-text
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_text as text

# Or install with a specific Version
!pip install -U "tensorflow==2.8.*"
!pip install -U "tensorflow-text==2.8.*"
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_text as text
```

**Old** First, install `tensorflow-text` version `2.8.*` like below:

```
!pip install -q -U "tensorflow-text==2.8.*"
```

Then import `tensorflow-text` like below:

```
import tensorflow_text as text
```

Comment: What is the logic here? by the way it solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: @albert, welcome, Because you want to use the latest version of `tensorflow-text` , `2.9.*` but other dependencies like python, and tensorflow that you use, have not the latest version.

Comment: Thank you for your hint!! It was solved with the following two lines. 
`!pip install -U "tensorflow==2.8.*"` <br>
`!pip install -U "tensorflow-text==2.8.*"`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried I'mahdi's answer and it was not working, but the following solution worked for me.

Here are the steps that solved it for me.

1. Visit the Tensorflow-Text official site (https://www.tensorflow.org/text)
2. There is a little scroll bar down the right side RUN IN COLAB NOTEBBOK you will see, click on it (else use this link https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/text/blob/master/docs/guide/bert_preprocessing_guide.ipynb)
3. In this notebook, change runtime to GPU and RUN cell by cell until the setup section
4. And then it will work (WAIT)
5. Delete all other cells except 1st 2 cells of Setup section
6. Then continue your code...

NOTE: If it didn't work try do the restart once again from step 1, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest Tensorflow version in colab with the following command -

```
!pip install tensorflow-text==2.13.0
```

Please restart the runtime after executing this command

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on google colab. My tensorflow_text was installed as:

!pip install tensorflow_text==2.12.1

It got resolved by restarting the colab session. Now I am able to simply import it as:

import tensorflow_text as text

works perfect!!